# Can a quasi-identity express that a function $f$ is surjective? And if not, can this be explained by duality?

Tags: logic, universal-algebra

Consider a first-order theory having a unary function symbol $f$. Then the following quasi-identity expresses that $f$ is injective.

$$\forall xy : f(x)=f(y) \rightarrow x=y$$

Alternatively, we can demand that $f$ be surjective by adjoining the following axiom.

$$\forall y\exists x : f(x)=y$$

Observe, however, that this isn't a quasi-identity.

**Question 0.** Is there a quasi-identity expressing that $f$ is surjective?

**Question 1.** If not, are sentences of the form [Universal quantifiers][Existential quantifiers][Equation] somehow "dual" to quasi-identities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no quasi-identity that will do it.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of structures for your signature, i.e. pairs of sets equipped with a map between them (or if you prefer, sets equipped with an endomap; the same argument works for both). Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the full subcategory of structures satisfying some given quasi-identities. It is not hard to see that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under (possibly infinite) products and subobjects. But this is not true for the subcategory where the equipped map is surjective. (Infinite products are a non-issue if you have the axiom of choice – but there are easy counterexamples to the closure under subobjects.)

Comment: Makes sense. Please comment if you have any thoughts or ideas about the second question.